# Are all plastic compression fittings interchangeable?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, pvc, kitchen-sink, abs

I need to rework the plumbing under my kitchen double sink. Currently, it consists of one brass drain pipe along with all ABS pipe and compression joints. Can I replace the pieces I need with their PVC counterparts or will there differences in diameters not allow this.

Answer (score 1):

My experiance in the UK is that compression waste pipe fittings are pretty tolerant about pipe sizes. For example a "40mm" compression fitting will clamp down on a pipe that is anywhere from about 40mm to 43mm in diameter.

I don't know if compression fittings sold in other countries are similar or not.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar; if you can get the threaded ferrule and gasket onto the old pipe, the change of materials won't be a problem as it's the gasket in the compression fitting that does the sealing.